# Redirect and pass a value from django to PHP

Tags: php, django, url, redirect

I have a php code sending data to django.
I want django to redirect response to another php page instead of the previous one.
Here is my view which is called from PHP :

```
def search(request):
    arg = { 'Score':clf.predict_proba(my_sample)}
    response=redirect('redirected_url.php',arg)
    return (HttpResponse(response)
```

query_arg is a value I want to pass to another php page and show it.
I have tried

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('redirected_url.php'.arg)
```

and it did not work either!
How should I proceed?

Best

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `redirect` with `arg` as a second parameter in Django. [That parameter determines whether it's a permanent redirect or not](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect). Regardless, the `*args` option there is for extra data to pass to `redirect`, not for your variables.

If you're redirecting to another page, you need to pass your variables as a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). For instance, you could pass a variable `name` when redirecting in Django this way:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('redirected_url.php?name=alex')
```

And then access it from your PHP script via the [superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) `$_GET['name']`.

Comment: Thx for reply.currently when I call the php code in url no riderction is done.I expect url change and going to other page but nothing happens!

Comment: If you're not getting redirected at all, then it sounds like your `search` method isn't getting run at all. Make sure your Django server's been restarted (so it's running the latest code) and check your console output for any errors. You should also check the Network tab of your browser developer tools to see what response you get from the server.

Comment: I checked them.When I sned normal HttpResponse bache it is done perfecly.But I nedd to redirect the response and show the value in another page.

Comment: What response do you get from the server when you redirect, as seen in your browser tools?

Comment: Nothing.In the redirected php page I have just var_dump('get:');
var_dump($_GET) to show the parameter.But nothing happens.No error!

Comment: Take a step back; forget the PHP page for the time being. Check the [network panel](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-panel-overview) to make sure the request is made to your Django app, and see what the [server response is](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-resource-details). Is it responding with a 3xx status code? Is it sending the correct `Location` header? If you visit that `Location` in your browser, does your PHP page run?